# Modify an index in SQL Server without dropping it

Tags: sql, sql-server, optimization, indexing

I want to modify an existing index and add some columns in the `INCLUDE` section. This is a pretty big table and the index would take a while to run.

Is there a way to write the index statement so that if I have to cancel the index modification the existing index won't be dropped?

Comment: It would seem more prudent to create a *new* index, and the `DROP` the old index once the new one is created?

Comment: How can I create it with the same name if it already exists? Create it with a different name and then rename it after dropping the old one?

Comment: Why does it need to have the same name? But yes, you could rename it afterwards, if needs must.

Comment: `CREATE INDEX ... WITH (DROP_EXISTING = ON, ONLINE = ON)` should do the trick, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-index-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#drop_existing---on--off- and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/perform-index-operations-online?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: I have an index idx_date ON (startDate). I want to modify it to include a few columns. 
idx_date ON (startDate) Include(name, region). I don't want to create a new index. I want to modify the existing index to include a few columns.

Comment: @Charlieface Thank you! Could you please briefly explain what those options do?

Comment: They're explained [in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-index-transact-sql), e.g. [`ONLINE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-index-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#online---on--off-) and [`DROP_EXISTING`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-index-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#drop_existing-clause).

Comment: I went through the documentation. The DROP_EXISTING doc mostly talks about recreating the clustered index. In my case, I want to recreate a non-clustered index. Does it not provide any significant advantages compared to drop and create statements in the case of non-clustered indexes? What happens when I use the DROP_EXISTING = ON when modifying the index and midway the index creation is canceled? Do I lose my original index that was being modified?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `CREATE INDEX...WITH(DROP_EXISITING = ON)` syntax to change an existing index in order to add addition key or included columns. This will leverage the existing index definition to avoid sorting when creating the new index.

For example, with the original index definition:

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON dbo.YourTable(col1)
    INCLUDE(col2);
```

This will add an included column::

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON dbo.YourTable(col1)
    INCLUDE(col2, col3)
    WITH(DROP_EXISTING = ON);
```

If you are using Enterprise Edition, consider `the ONLINE = ON` option too to avoid a schema modification lock on the table for the duration of the operation.

Comment: @Charlieface, agreed. Added that to my answer.

Comment: What does ONLINE = ON do?

Comment: @lifeisajourney short answer: it does not lock table.